# null credentials from Ticket Cache Kerberos

Tags: caching, kerberos

i have a krb5 database on linux CentOS and i made a java client kerberos...but he don't aquire TGT from cache..Cannot import null name is because he don't find the ticket cache right? JAAS Authentication employing the Krb5LoginModule will fail with the following error:

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is /tmp/krb5cc_0 isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is null
null credentials from Ticket Cache
Java config name: krb5.ini
Loaded from Java config
Looking for keys for: user1@KDC.COM
Key for the principal user1@KDC.COM not available in default key tab
        [Krb5LoginModule] user entered username: user1

>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 16.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=10.10.21.28 UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=122
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=10.10.21.28 UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=122
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=274
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 136

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 11
     PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 16, salt = KDC.COMuser1

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 16, salt = KDC.COMuser1, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 133

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove 10.10.21.28
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
     cTime is Mon Jun 02 23:28:55 CEST 1986 518131735000
     sTime is Fri Sep 15 12:22:05 CEST 2017 1505470925000
     suSec is 562972
     error code is 25
     error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
     cname is user1@KDC.COM
     sname is krbtgt/KDC.COM@KDC.COM
     eData provided.
     msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 136

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 11
     PA-ETYPE-INFO etype = 16, salt = KDC.COMuser1

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 19
     PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 16, salt = KDC.COMuser1, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 2
     PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
     PA-DATA type = 133

KRBError received: NEEDED_PREAUTH
KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 16.
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 16.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Des3CbcHmacSha1KdEType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=10.10.21.28 UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=210
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=10.10.21.28 UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=210
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=685
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove 10.10.21.28
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Des3CbcHmacSha1KdEType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply user1
principal is user1@KDC.COM
Commit Succeeded 

GSSException: Cannot import null name
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:164)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:151)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:128)
    at kerby.ClientKerberosAuthentication.initiateSecurityContext(ClientKerberosAuthentication.java:92)
    at kerby.ClientKerberosAuthentication.main(ClientKerberosAuthentication.java:47)
There was an error during the security context initiation
```

I setProperty for krb5 conf in the root path:

```
[libdefaults]
         default_realm = KDC.COM
         dns_lookup_realm = false
         dns_lookup_kdc = true
         ticket_lifetime = 24h
         forwardable = true
         udp_preference_limit = 1000000
         default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1
         default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1
         permitted_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1

[realms]
        KDC.COM = {
             kdc = 10.10.21.28
             admin_server = 10.10.21.28
             default_domain = kdc.com
         }

[domain_realm]
         .kdc.com = KDC.COM
         kdc.com = KDC.COM


[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE=/var/log/kadm5.log
```

My jaas.conf file is this:

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  debug=true
  useTicketCache=true
  ticketCache="/tmp/krb5cc_0";
};
```

I share my client class too:

```
public class Client {

  static Oid krb5Oid;

  public static void main( String[] args) {

    // Oid mechanism = use Kerberos V5 as the security mechanism.
    try {
      krb5Oid = new Oid( "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
    }
    catch (GSSException e) {
      System.err.println("Client: Error obtaining Kerberos V5 OID: " + e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    // 1. Set up Kerberos properties.
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
      props.load( new FileInputStream("client.properties"));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Client: Error opening properties file '"+props+"': " + e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.setProperty( "sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", "./jaas.config");
    System.setProperty( "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.ini");
    String username = props.getProperty( "client.principal.name");
    String password = props.getProperty( "client.password");

    // 2. Authenticate against the KDC using JAAS and return the Subject.
    LoginContext loginCtx = null;
    // "Client" references the corresponding JAAS configuration section in the jaas.conf file.
    try {
      loginCtx = new LoginContext("Client", new Krb5CallbackHandler(username, password));
      loginCtx.login();
    }
    catch ( LoginException e) {
      System.err.println("Client: There was an error during the JAAS login: " + e);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit( -1);
    }

    Subject subject = loginCtx.getSubject();

    // 3. Connect to service.
    String hostName = "http://127.0.0.1";
    int port = 22;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
      socket = new Socket(hostName,port);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Client: There was an error connecting to the server: hostname " + hostName + " not found.");
        System.exit( -1);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Client: There was an error connecting to the server: " + e);
        System.exit( -1);
    }

    final DataInputStream inStream;
    final DataOutputStream outStream;

    try {
      inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

      // 4. Authenticate with service.
      String servicePrincipalName = props.getProperty("service.principal.name");
      GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
      GSSName serverName = null;

      try { 
        serverName = manager.createName( servicePrincipalName, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
      }
      catch (GSSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Client: There was an error in creating a name for the host-based service that we want to connect to.");
        System.exit(-1);
      }

      System.out.println("Client: Initiating security context with serverName " + serverName);

      try {
        final GSSContext context = manager.createContext( serverName, 
                                                          krb5Oid, 
                                                          null,
                                                          GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);

        // The GSS context initiation has to be performed as a privileged action.
        GSSContext serviceTicket = Subject.doAs( subject, new PrivilegedAction<GSSContext>() {
            public GSSContext run() {
              try {
                context.requestMutualAuth( false);
                context.requestCredDeleg( false);

                int retval;
                while(!context.isEstablished()) {
                  context.initSecContext(inStream,outStream);
                }
                return context;
              }
              catch (GSSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
              }
            }
          });

        if (serviceTicket != null) {
          System.out.println("Client obtained service ticket for service : " + servicePrincipalName);
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Client failed to obtain service ticket for service : " + servicePrincipalName);
          System.exit(-1);
        }
      }
      catch (GSSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    }
    catch ( IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println( "Client: There was an IO error");
      System.exit( -1);
    }
  }

}
```

I made kadm5.keytab for all hosts and pass with the syntax: ktadd -k /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab kadmin/admin ktadd -k /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab kadmin/changepw

```
^E^B^@^@^@K^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^R^@ ó^?RT9p<9b>»TNi<93><95>Ø¦¯<8b><8e>rÿðfHW<95>^L^<97>bÃÏ^B^@^@^@^B^@^@^@;^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^Q^@^P<80>w.^X<92>õ²^U¤}AE¹#^O4^@^@^@^B^@^@^@C^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^P^@^X÷p^G¶#§<8a>¨­<98>=n^U^\æp¿åýãanº¹^@^@^@^B^@^@^@;^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^W^@^P^P^QÖ_Ûã<88><94>\Ñ]¾<99>Ó<99> ^@^@^@^B^@^@^@K^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^Z^@ =êæ^B­g^N<95><86>}¦Ø©8
<8d>k·erT&1÷-×Ã-^±<9c>î^@^@^@^B^@^@^@;^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^Y^@^PH Õ@`Ñ^?2^B>ÖÚT:<93>¿^@^@^@^B^@^@^@3^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^H^@^H<8f>^MÓñIÐX<8c>^@^@^@^B^@^@^@3^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Eadmin^@^@^@^AY½^T@^B^@^C^@^H2n<8f>na«<9b>¹^@^@^@^B^@^@^@N^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^R^@ ñ»<8b>¿¥Zâ<86>q
<H^?^R<80>à<9b>ødc,|<88>Fö(<8f>^SÓ>å®^@^@^@^B^@^@^@>^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^Q^@^P<93><8f>}'@<88>Ne^T<99>E^@<8f>;¤<8a>^@^@^@^B^@^@^@F^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^P^@^Xº^S<83>Ú<8f>Ç<83>ï^UL/ºn¨°d¤à¿^N«Ö@<94>^@^@^@^B^@^@^@>^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^W^@^P^O#Ç^C6^S:<87><99>ÆÅ^S7F^F     ^@^@^@^B^@^@^@N^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^Z^@ eÉ©<8a>_ý ý^W$Êz<9e>%<84><86>Z°OÙ5<89>çÏÝ<8d>/<85>¥P<95>ë^@^@^@^B^@^@^@>^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^Y^@^POw»lÈ^K<9a>^Xmë^P<8e>µ<9e>^\^N^@^@^@^B^@^@^@6^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^H^@^HJ<89>@¼E­µÓ^@^@^@^B^@^@^@6^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Fkadmin^@^Hchangepw^@^@^@^AY½^TH^B^@^C^@^HE®Î<8c>§^?÷Ú^@^@^@^B
```

Then add a principal host and krb5.keytab with syntax: ktadd -k /etc/krb5.keytab host/server.kdc.com

```
^E^B^@^@^@R^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^R^@ »©<87>=àç<8c>ÿ^@^SÐs%$þ^YØ]^MÕg<8e>^R<8a>Z^S
Mè^U^Rü^@^@^@^B^@^@^@B^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^Q^@^P<9b>^_
ë^H§O<88>Y\«¥:^G¤ÿ^@^@^@^B^@^@^@J^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^P^@^X8a^A^G^Mn|<91>¤Â°|/FJãÁûÚÕ,|Lì^@^@^@^B^@^@^@B^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^W^@^P¬Ë^^?ü^?'¢<9a>k5öÉá7ï^@^@^@^B^@^@^@R^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^Z^@ >*ë^W9s^H^PhgÓ^E³^V½å© {ÛôG1^^h<80>È^Y7reó^@^@^@^B^@^@^@B^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^Y^@^PÌ3ê("¦'×AX^YU<8d>^Q¤<95>^@^@^@^B^@^@^@:^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^H^@^HTÓknÖb=#^@^@^@^B^@^@^@:^@^B^@^GKDC.COM^@^Dhost^@^Nserver.kdc.com^@^@^@^AY½^U]^B^@^C^@^Håôa^KåpÄ¿^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@
```

Comment: Show us the syntax you used to create the keytab.  Also show us the contents of the keytab itself by editing in Notepad++.  Don't make any changes though, just need to peek at what is inside.  Most of it is encrypted but I want to see the non-encrypted part.

Comment: I did not answer to you, sorry..

Comment: No, you need to edit everything you added into your question - not as answers!

Comment: done, i edit all into my question @T-Heron

Comment: Your keytab has GKDC.COM encoded in it while the krb5.conf shows KDC.COM in it.  That's a major problem, nothing will work that way.

Comment: So i can change only the krb5.conf or i must do new keytab? and why has GKDC.COM?

Comment: The realm name in the keytab has to match the realm name of Kerberos realm clients are authenticating to.  And that should match the name in krb5.conf as well.

Comment: i deleted the kadm5.keytab file and make it another one but i have the same result

Comment: Can u please take a look at client.java? i think hostname "localhost" is not right..so i can exclude all and take a look better at keytab file

Comment: @mihaimaier : Have you got resolution to this issue? I am also facing the same problem if you solution, can you help me with that?